# STM32F103ZET6 USART with DMA behaves differently in debug versus reset run

Tags: stm32, stm32f10x, dma

I am using the STM32F103ZET6 MCU and am having a weird problem where if I program and debug or program and reset my MCU the USART3 used to communicate with a slave device does not work. In debug there is no USART data going into memory from the DMA, and I have got it on a scope that the slave device is constantly sending data. I have checked:

1. The clocks are configured at appropriate speeds.
2. The USART is still working using USART3_getchar(0)
3. re-initiliasing my USART3.
4. BOOT0 pin is low in debug.
5. The DMA channel is not being used by anything else.

I have checked the reference manual and device datasheet but am struggling to debug/check settings in code to see the difference between debug/reset run.

```
// Local Variables
GPIO_InitTypeDef    GPIO_InitStructure;
NVIC_InitTypeDef    NVIC_InitStructure;
USART_InitTypeDef   USART_InitStructure;
USART_ClockInitTypeDef USART_ClockInitStructure;

// Code
// Configure UART
RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_USART3 | RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOB | RCC_APB2Periph_AFIO, ENABLE);     // USART3 Periph clock enable

// Configure Pins
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin                     =  UART3_RX_PIN;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed                   =  GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode                    =  GPIO_Mode_IPD;
GPIO_Init(UART3_PORT, &GPIO_InitStructure);

GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin                     =  UART3_TX_PIN;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed                   =  GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode                    =  GPIO_Mode_AF_PP;
GPIO_Init(UART3_PORT, &GPIO_InitStructure);

#if(UART3_TX_FLOW_CTS_EN    == 1)                                                       
// Enable USART3 CTS pin
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin                     =  UART3_CTS_PIN;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed                   =  GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode                    =  GPIO_Mode_IN_FLOATING;
GPIO_Init(UART3_PORT, &GPIO_InitStructure);
#endif

#if(UART3_RX_FLOW_RTS_EN    == 1)                                                       
// Enable USART3 RTS pin
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin                     =  UART3_RTS_PIN;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed                   =  GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode                    =  GPIO_Mode_Out_PP;
GPIO_Init(UART3_PORT, &GPIO_InitStructure);

mCSP_USART3_RTS_PIN_GO;                                                             
// initialise the RTS pin as go
#endif

st_uart3_tx_glb.timeout_timer_u16               =  UART3_TX_TIMEOUT;
while(  (uart3_tx_flg                           == 0)   &&
#if(UART3_TX_FLOW_CTS_EN    == 1)

        (mCSP_USART3_CTS_READ                   == 0)   &&
#endif
        (st_uart3_tx_glb.timeout_timer_u16      >  0)   );

//Set USART3 Clock
USART_ClockStructInit(&USART_ClockInitStructure);
USART_ClockInit(USART3, &USART_ClockInitStructure);

USART_InitStructure.USART_BaudRate                  =  baud_rate_u32;
USART_InitStructure.USART_WordLength                =  USART_WordLength_8b;
USART_InitStructure.USART_StopBits                  =  USART_StopBits_1;
USART_InitStructure.USART_Parity                    =  USART_Parity_No;
#if(UART3_TX_FLOW_CTS_EN    == 1)
USART_InitStructure.USART_HardwareFlowControl       =  
USART_HardwareFlowControl_CTS;  // Enable USART3 CTS pin
#else
USART_InitStructure.USART_HardwareFlowControl       =  
USART_HardwareFlowControl_None;
#endif
USART_InitStructure.USART_Mode                      =  USART_Mode_Rx | 
USART_Mode_Tx;
USART_Init(USART3, &USART_InitStructure);

// Enable interrupts
USART_ITConfig(USART3, USART_IT_RXNE, ENABLE);
DMA_ITConfig(DMA1_Channel2, DMA_IT_TC, ENABLE);

// Enable modules
USART_Cmd(USART3, ENABLE);
USART_DMACmd(USART3, USART_DMAReq_Rx, ENABLE);

// Enable the UART3 Interupt
//  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel                      =  USART3_IRQn;
// NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority=USART3_IRQ_PREM_PRI;
//  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority   = USART3_IRQ_SUB_PRI;
//  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd                   =  ENABLE;
//  NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);

// Configure DMA
RCC_AHBPeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_DMA1, ENABLE);                                  // DMA1 Periph clock enable

st_uart3_tx_glb.cnt_u8                              =  st_uart3_tx_glb.wr_index_u8;

DMA_DeInit(DMA1_Channel2);
DMA_StructInit(&DMA_UART3_InitStructure);
DMA_UART3_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralBaseAddr      =  (uint32_t)&USART3->DR;
DMA_UART3_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryBaseAddr          =  (uint32_t)uart3_rx_buffer_a_u8_glb;
DMA_UART3_InitStructure.DMA_DIR                     =  DMA_DIR_PeripheralSRC;
DMA_UART3_InitStructure.DMA_BufferSize              =  st_uart3_tx_glb.cnt_u8;
DMA_UART3_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralInc           =  DMA_PeripheralInc_Disable;
DMA_UART3_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryInc               =  DMA_MemoryInc_Enable;
DMA_UART3_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralDataSize      =  DMA_PeripheralDataSize_Byte;
DMA_UART3_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryDataSize          =  DMA_MemoryDataSize_Byte;
DMA_UART3_InitStructure.DMA_Mode                    =  DMA_Mode_Circular;
DMA_UART3_InitStructure.DMA_Priority                =  DMA_Priority_VeryHigh;
DMA_UART3_InitStructure.DMA_M2M                     =  DMA_M2M_Disable;
DMA_Init(DMA1_Channel2, &DMA_UART3_InitStructure);

// Enable the DMA complete Interupt
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel                      =  DMA1_Channel2_IRQn;
NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);

DMA_Cmd(DMA1_Channel2, ENABLE);
```

Comment: The DMA and USART cannot be halted during debug, you could get out-of-sync if you miss interrupts this way. See DBGMCU_CR.

Comment: I can see the bit definition in stm32f10x.h but I am not sure, do I need to define speicifc DBGMCU_CR bits for USART and DMA to work in debug? I don't think i've needed to do this before.
I am not halting the CPU, I am simply waiting for a bit to come into the memory and halting after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was that USART3 is on APB1 and not APB2 clock and was therefore not being enabled but in the bootloader the APB1 USART3 clock was being enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Local structs should be initialised, otherwise some fields can get unpredictable values:

```
GPIO_InitTypeDef    GPIO_InitStructure={};
NVIC_InitTypeDef    NVIC_InitStructure={};
USART_InitTypeDef   USART_InitStructure={};
USART_ClockInitTypeDef USART_ClockInitStructure={};
```

`mCSP_USART3_RTS_PIN_GO;` What does this statement do? Is it a macro or what?

These flags should be declared `volatile`, otherwise you can get different behaviour at different optimization settings:

```
while(  (uart3_tx_flg                           == 0)   &&
#if(UART3_TX_FLOW_CTS_EN    == 1)
    (mCSP_USART3_CTS_READ                   == 0)   &&
#endif
    (st_uart3_tx_glb.timeout_timer_u16      >  0)   );
```